# Error: Systemd start for glusterfs-server failed

Tags: linux, puppet, glusterfs

I keep getting the error below when I run `puppet agent -t` but when I check the gluster service, the service is already running. What do I need to do to fix this error that I keep getting?

```
Error: Systemd start for glusterfs-server failed!
journalctl log for glusterfs-server:
-- No entries --

Error: /Stage[main]/Gluster::Service/Service[glusterfs-server]/ensure: 
change from stopped to running failed: Systemd start for glusterfs-server 
failed!
journalctl log for glusterfs-server:
-- No entries --
```